# Linux Software to Decoding Old Surround Audio Formats

Tags: sound

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 LTS (64 bit Linux).

I wonder if there is some Linux native software to decoding old surround audio formats like: SQ Quadraphonic, QS Quadraphonic, Dolby Pro Logic II, and others.

Some idea?

Comment: Already tried vlc, with extra codecs? Maybe carefully from deb-multimedia.org?

Comment: Do you have links to any of these files?

Comment: Maybe I wrote my idea with the wrong words... I want a software which takes the SQ audio (from a vinyl record), decodes it from 2 to 4 audio channels and..., makes the 4 separate audio tracks into a single audio file format (*.wav). That's what I want. I know VLC lets me to hear the decoded audio, but...

Comment: There are some SQ Quadraphonic audio files in YouTube, but... I don't know if are recorded directly from the original vinyl records.